# UWP Change color settings of Disabled slider

Tags: win-universal-app

I need to change color setting of the disabled slider. It should be very easy to do this, but I don't know how to do this in UWP app for Win10.

I try all methods that described in this question: [Change slider bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123301/change-slider-bar-color), but it's still wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stamos said, you can do it with Blend, or you can just modify the template of the `Slider` in the XAML design.

To do this, you can open the Document Outline, choose your `Slider` and right click on it, then Edit Template, and Edit a Copy like in the picture below:

[image]

Now in the default style, you can find the disabled visual state, and you can modify the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` inside of it to your expected style.

For example you can change the horizontal silder when it is disabled like this:

```cs
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

It's very easy to modify the default template of controls, or it's also convenient to do this work with blend, you can choose one method to complete this work.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the color of the default template [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299153.aspx)
and add the overwrite color into your `ResourceDictionary` in App.xml by following format:

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="name of the key" Color="#7FF1F1F1" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use blend.

1. Right click on your file in VS ex MainPage.xaml then click Design with Blend.
2. On the Objects and Timeline right click the slider and select Edit
       Template > Edit a Copy > OK (or you can change where it will be
       saved).
3. Now you are in the Template Design. Click States(above Objects and Timeline)
4. Select Disabled.
5. Now you are in Rec Mode, a red dot will appear.
6. While in Rec Mode select the elements of the slide and change their
   color.(HorizontalThumb , VerticalThumb ,HorizontalTrackRect etc...)
7. Done, test it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299153.aspx), following is the **Disabled** `VisualState` for `Slider` which contains named brushes that you need to play with.

```
 <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
          <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

In your **ResourceDisctionary**, you can define

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush">#0000FF</SolidColorBrush>
```

Add **ResourceDictionary** in App.xaml

```
<Application
 ... >

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Brushes.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Result** looks like this

[image]